# Ошибка при подключении по IPv6

Tags: apache, debian, apache2, vps, ipv6

Когда подключаюсь к сайту посредством IPv6 адрес: [2a05:480:0:9892::2]:8080

Вижу следующую страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При подключении по IPv4\обычному адресу такого не возникает. В чем проблема? Как это исправить? 
Вроде прослушивания включена и все должо работать, но не судьба
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Адрес сайта: https://avtoday.com.ua

Comment: ipv6-адрес ничем не хуже и не лучше ipv4-адреса в качестве [server_name](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/server_names.html). если хотите обращаться по нему, то надо его добавить в список. но вам **явно** не это требуется.